# How to Find an HTML Element in a Javascript Array That Has a Certain Styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, filter

I am making a website with sections. Basically, you press a button on the bottom of the page and it will show the div connected to that button.

So with styling I only have hiding the four sections and showing the "home" section:

```
.container-pages {
    display: none;
}

#home-page {
    display: block;
}
```

And with HTML its just the sections and buttons...

```
<!--sections-->
<div id="home-page" class="container-pages">
        <h1>HOME</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="start-page" class="container-pages">
        <h1>START</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="learn-page" class="container-pages">
        <h1>LEARN</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-page" class="container-pages">
        <h1>CONTACT</h1>
    </div>
    
<!--buttons-->
    <div id="bottom-menu">
        <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="home-button">HOME</div>
        <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="start-button">START A PROJECT</div>
        <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="learn-button">LEARN</div>
        <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="contact-button">CONTACT US</div>
    </div>
```

Now the JavaScript:

```
// creating an array with the 4 html sections (pages):
const pages = [...document.getElementsByClassName('container-pages')];
```

```js
// creating an array with the 4 html sections (pages):
const pages = [...document.getElementsByClassName('container-pages')];
```

```css
.container-pages {
  display: none;
}

#home-page {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--sections-->
<div id="home-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>HOME</h1>
</div>
<div id="start-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>START</h1>
</div>
<div id="learn-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>LEARN</h1>
</div>
<div id="contact-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>CONTACT</h1>
</div>

<!--buttons-->
<div id="bottom-menu">
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="home-button">HOME</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="start-button">START A PROJECT</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="learn-button">LEARN</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="contact-button">CONTACT US</div>
</div>
```

So how do I filter this array that it makes a new array with just the `<divs>` that have the style of `display: block;` ?

I've tried:

```
const currentSelection = pages.filter(div => div.style.display == 'block');
```

But when I log `currentSelection` on the console I get an empty array.

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks in advance,
Menmoe.

Comment: What if you try adding a class to the target div when the button is clicked? And have that class override display none to display block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of easy approaches, one of which is to use the same approach as yourself but taking into account that `element.style.display === 'block'` will only match *if* `display: block` was set in the inline `style` attribute. If the styles were set in a stylesheet – or in a `<style>` element – then instead we have to use `window.getComputedStyle(element, state).propertyName` instead in order to retrieve the computed/rendered properties applied to the element:

```js
// creating an array with the 4 html sections (pages):
const pages = [...document.getElementsByClassName('container-pages')],
  // we use the Array.prototype.filter() method, along with an anonymous Arrow function
  // to test each element of the 'pages' Array, to retain only those elements whose
  // 'display' is exactly equal to 'block':
  visible = pages.filter((page) => window.getComputedStyle(page, null).display === 'block'),
  // here we do exactly the same, but we filter for those pages that are currently
  // set to 'display: none':
  hidden = pages.filter((page) => window.getComputedStyle(page, null).display === 'none');

console.log(visible, hidden);
```

```css
.container-pages {
  display: none;
}

#home-page {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--sections-->
<div id="home-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>HOME</h1>
</div>
<div id="start-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>START</h1>
</div>
<div id="learn-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>LEARN</h1>
</div>
<div id="contact-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>CONTACT</h1>
</div>

<!--buttons-->
<div id="bottom-menu">
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="home-button">HOME</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="start-button">START A PROJECT</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="learn-button">LEARN</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="contact-button">CONTACT US</div>
</div>
```

While the above approach works, it would be simpler still to use the `hidden` attribute to hide the relevant elements:

```js
// creating an array with the 4 html sections (pages):
const pages = [...document.getElementsByClassName('container-pages')],
  // we use the Array.prototype.filter() method, along with an anonymous Arrow function
  // to test each element of the 'pages' Array, to retain only those elements whose
  // 'hidden' property is set to false (and are therefore visible):
  visible = pages.filter((page) => page.hidden === false),
  // here we do exactly the same, but we filter for those pages whose 'hidden'
  // property is equal to true, and are therefore hidden:
  hidden = pages.filter((page) => page.hidden === true);

console.log(visible, hidden);
```

```html
<!--sections-->
<div id="home-page" class="container-pages">
  <h1>HOME</h1>
</div>
<div id="start-page" class="container-pages" hidden>
  <h1>START</h1>
</div>
<div id="learn-page" class="container-pages" hidden>
  <h1>LEARN</h1>
</div>
<div id="contact-page" class="container-pages" hidden>
  <h1>CONTACT</h1>
</div>

<!--buttons-->
<div id="bottom-menu">
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="home-button">HOME</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="start-button">START A PROJECT</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="learn-button">LEARN</div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons bottom-menu-items" id="contact-button">CONTACT US</div>
</div>
```

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).